# Don't Freak Out and Don't Sweat It

Tags: riddle, pattern

50 years ago, there was a far-out party.
Who was the fourth cat that made it a gas?

Bo Dee,
  Lee Shore,
  Woz Fromm

Spelling doesn't matter, as long as it sounds right.

Comment: Care to post any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Initial thoughts, but not really an answer yet...

I have two trains of thought right now, the first is related to "Who was the fourth cat that made it a gas?"

> This reminds me of the "Neon Tiger", because Neon is a noble gas, and a Tiger is a kind of cat.

The other is that "Bo Dee, Lee Shore, Woz Fromm"

> This sounds like "Body Leisure Was From" when pronounced.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here, or how to connect these. I'm also not sure how the title and 50 years ago play into this...

Comment: >! Your first train goes nowhere, but your second train is on the right track.